# streamlining creating of packages and views

Tags: sql, oracle

I have few SQL scripts which setups the db of an app. have few scripts creating packages which has few references of views, and similarly have scripts for creating views which has references of packages.

Is there a way to separate these two scripts which would then individually create only packages or views respectively.

Or any alternate to work on this.

Comment: Adding 'Circular Reference' text hoping it will be added to SO index and help others find this good question & answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to calculate the reference graph manually and then order the execution of the scripts accordingly.

So you need to create a set of scripts views1.sql, views2.sql, ... and packages1.sql, packages2.sql, ...
Views1.sql contains only views that are not referencing any packages.
Packages1.sql contains only packages that are not referencing any views.
Views2.sql contains only views that are referencing packages from packages1.sql.
Packages2.sql contains only packages that are referencing views from views1.sql.

And so on until you are finished.

Comment: @rics. +1. Thanks for your prompt reply. Infact I am doing the same thing by calling the scripts in that sequence. Wanted to know if there was a better way to deal with it.

Comment: I had a package referencing a view for which the same view referenced another function in the package. Not sure if this idea would have worked. I ended up compiling the Spec first, then the view referencing the package, then the Body. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First, create the package specifications.

Second, create the views -- they reference the specification, not the body.

Third, create the package bodies -- they reference the views.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Our DBA prefers all the DDL compile like magic so this was better than compiling invalid. First time I've encountered this had a view that referenced a function in the package and another function in the package referenced the same view. Took me while to find this- was using circular reference as my search criteria.

Answer (score 3):

You could just create all your views first using the syntax

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW
```

which creates a view even if the referenced objects don't exist yet, then create all your package specs, then the bodies.

Now you could compile all invalid objects or just let Oracle take care of it (see this link)

[Ask Tom - "invalid objects"](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7496297887874)